# Why is there no current in this part of the circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

Can someone give an explanation to why there no current in *i<sub>0</sub>* (or why does *i<sub>0</sub>* equal 0)? It was a step I had to know *before* using Kirchoff's laws.

Also, is there a voltage across the nodes that *i<sub>0</sub>* goes between?

Comment: There's no return path. The entire lower conductor is one node.

Comment: Also, if you remember the current into a node = current out of a node, then you can see that the net current between those two nodes must be zero.

Comment: Related: [Kirchhoff's Current Law at the ground node?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108798/)

Comment: Specifically, look up the *cut-set* version of the Kirchoff Current Law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming ideal circuit elements and conductors:**

Simply because there is no return path for \$i_o\$.

The entire lower line (call it *ground* or *common*) in the schematic is considered to be one node, therefore there is considered to be no voltage difference across it either.

(*Suppose* that there was a current flowing in \$i_o\$. Then the only way back to the starting point would be trough the same node but in opposite direction, meaning that the sum of the currents is \$i_o + (- i_o) = 0\$.)

Answer (score 0):

This would be like taking a battery and connecting only one terminal of it to your circuit. You need a path for the current to return