# Network Analysis for finding power delivered

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, network, voltage-source

[image]

We need to find the power delivered by the 5V source in the above network. I usually apply superposition theorem when I need to find the power delivered by a source when there are many power sources in the same circuit. But here I am not able to understand how to approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, calculate the current through the `3 Ω` and `2 Ω` resistors by simple Ohm's law (`I = V⁄R`). The result is shown in the following figure (they are denoted by `I1` and `I2`).

[image: DC Network Analysis]

Next task is to calculate the current through the `5V` source which is denoted by `I3`. We can use        [*Kirchoff's Current Law (KCL)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) either at Network 1 or Network 2.

Lets say we apply KCL at Network 1. Here, we can write -

`I2 + I3 = I1`

Or,

`I3 = I1 - I2`

Or,

`I3 = 2A - 1A = 1A`

So, we have found the value of current through the voltage source is `1A`. So, the supplied power by the voltage source is `5 × 1 = 5W`.

Comment: Wow, that's a much simple method.

Answer (score 1):

1. Since you know the voltage across each resistor, you can find the current through it.
2. Knowing that, you can use the cut-set form of KCL to find the current through the 5 V source.
3. Knowing the voltage and current through the source, you can find the power it delivers to (or absorbs from) the rest of the circuit.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. So I need to use knowledge of Graph Theory here. Ok.

Comment: Most of the graph theory is only needed if you want to program a computer to find the necessary cut sets to fully analyze a circuit. To solve this problem you just need to know that if you draw a line that divides the circuit in two, the algebraic sum of currents across that line must be zero. More detail in [an old answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108808/6334) of mine.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again. Is Deoser Kuh a good book for Circuit Analysis? Or I should use Hayt Kemmerly?

Comment: Chua, Desoer & Kuh is the one I learned from, but that was a long time ago.

Comment: I also read some chapters from it and I think now also its worth reading.